# Как поместить Screen под MDToolbar при этом MDNavigationDrawer оставить над MDToolbar?

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть файл разметки `file.kv`

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 50
        title: "ZW"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'account'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            elevation: 0
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            on_release:
                root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'account'



    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        WindowsManager:
            id: screen_manager

            ScreenMain:
                name: "main"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "main"
                    halign: "center"

            ScreenThemes:
                name: "theme"

            .....

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

выглядит это все дело вот так:

[image: Меню и скрины над тулбаром]

`MDToolbar` находится над всеми элементами `Screen` под ним и меню `MDNavigationDrawer` так же под ним. Но я пытаюсь достичь немного иного эффекта:
вот такого

[image: Меню над баром и скрины под баром]

`Screen` должны быть под `MDToolbar` а меню `MDNavigationDrawer` над `MDToolbar`.
Если изменить

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

на

```
Screen:
```

то я получаю меню `MDNavigationDrawer` над `MDToolbar` но и `Screen` также выезжает над `MDToolbar`.

[image: Меню над баром и скрины под баром]

Я перепробовал множество комбинаций, но не пришел к желаемому результату... Например, так же, пробовал сделать отступ в `Screen` который выезжает на `MDToolbar`. Но из-за того, что пропорции экрана разные, получается не совсем нормальное изображение на различных устройствах. Лучше всего использовать

```
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
```

но никак не удается правильно расположить элементы так чтобы достичь результат, который покажу ниже в скриншотах.

[image: Меню над баром и скрины под баром]
[image: Меню над баром и скрины под баром]

Я все еще пытаюсь использовать различные комбинации, время от времени, как только найду решение тут же сообщу сообществу. Я понимаю, что данная задача может, по сути, оказаться тривиальной, но, к сожалению, вызывает трудности =(

Одно из решения представлено ниже в коде:

```
FloatLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.08 # 1, None
                           # size: 0, 60
        elevation: 10
        title: "ZW"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'account'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            elevation: 0
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            on_release: root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'account'

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        WindowsManager:
            id: screen_manager
            size_hint: None, 0.92

            ScreenMain:
                name: "main"
```

по соотношению сторон процентами, но так же питылся установить фиксированый размер `MDToolbar`, что удалось (в коде значение закоментировано), но фиксированый размер отсупа сверху в `WindowsManager`(Он же наследован от `ScreenManager`) не удалось установить. Может кто-то имеет решение лучше =) потому как данное решение на очень длинном экране, либо на очень коротком экране, будет выглядеть очень плохо...